# Laracast Video(Push Events to the Client) error?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I try to create event handling...so i followed this video tutorial ..everything working perfect. but in last minute video when i try to show user name in **list view** its not updating in real time as list view but i checked **console.log('users')** each object i can get it from my console.... but in view no updates or no errors ......... what is error ?
This is video tutorial - [LINK](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/12)

```
<body>
    <ul id="users">
            <li v-repeat="user: users">@{{ user.name }}</li>
        </ul>
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/3.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.20/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>
//    (function () {
//        var pusher = new Pusher('82355e6cc93e7a15d7d5', {
//            encrypted: true
//        });
//
//        var channel = pusher.subscribe('test');
//        channel.bind('App\\Events\\UserHasRegistered', function(data) {
//            console.log(data);
//        });
//    })();

   new Vue({
     el: '#users',
    data:{
            users:[]
        },
ready: function(){
var pusher = new Pusher('82355e6cc93e7a15d7d5', {
               encrypted: true
           });
pusher.subscribe('test')
                    .bind('App\\Events\\UserHasRegistered',this.addUser);
        },
methods: {
            addUser: function(user){
                this.users.push(user);
            }
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v-repeat` directive is deprecated in version 1.0 and replaced with the `v-for`.

> 1.0 replaces the old `v-repeat` directive with `v-for`. In addition to providing the same functionality and more intuitive scoping, `v-for` provides up to **100%** initial render performance boost when rendering large lists and tables!

http://vuejs.org/2015/10/26/1.0.0-release/#Faster-Initial-Rendering